# How organize uploaded media in WP?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media, media-library, library

I am new in WordPress and I came from Joomla.

I am having some problem to understand how can I (if I can do it...) organize the uploaded media into folders and subfolders using WordPress.

If I go in my backend administration panel I have the **Media** sub panel in which I can add a file (for example a jpg image). The problem is that all files are added in the same library.

I want to organize my library having subcategory\subfolder in which the uploaded files are stored.

For example I want have category image for: "Spring articles images" and "project management articles image", etc.

How can do it?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't support this natively, but there are many different plugins out there that you can use for that purpose.

[Here's a link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=media+library+categories&sort=) to get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best plug in to solve this problem is Media File Manager Advanced.
I let you check the description of it at: http://wordpress.org/plugins/media-file-manager-advanced/